# Cassandra operation timed out

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cassandra, timeout

Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.',
  info: 'Represents an error message from the server',
  code: 4608,
  consistencies: 1,
  received: 0,
  blockFor: 1,
  isDataPresent: 0,
  ...

I get this error a few times a day trying to do SELECT queries on my cassandra cluster. We have a 3 node cluster on m1.large aws instances. They succeed most of the time, but every once in a while we get the above error. We are not in production yet so all tables are small. We dont have any tables over a few thousand rows and the same queries complete fine other times. Raising the time out time is not an option and I don't believe it will solve the problem (the queries should be short and the query in the error is not the same each time)

Could this be some connection going stale between nodes or network issue? What's the best way to test for these? I also only see this error on my client side, is there somewhere I should be seeing this in the cassandra logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually an error coming back from the C* server that is responsible for handling your request (aka 'the coordinator').

It looks like you are querying with a consistency level of 'ONE' so only 1 replica holding the data needs to respond to the coordinator within the configured `read_request_timeout_in_ms` in your cassandra.yaml file on the server (default is 5 seconds), but no replicas responded within that time period.

Timeouts can happen and your application should be prepared handle them based on your preferences (either flat out fail, retry, increase replication factor to make it less likely, etc.)

Here are a few things you should consider:

1. Increase the replication factor of the keyspace you are querying data from.  If your replication factor is 1,  you are dependent on 1 node to be available to respond to queries for a particular partition.   Increasing your RF to something like 3 will make your application more resilient to poorly-performing nodes or nodes going down.
2. Configure your [RetryPolicy](http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/tuning-policies/#retry-policy) to retry reads depending on how you'd like it to behave.  The default with the nodejs-driver is to only retry reads once and only if `received` > `blockFor` (which in your case it wasn't).
3. Increase `read_request_timeout_in_ms` in your cassandra.yaml.  I would discourage this though, 5000ms should be more than enough unless you have a poor configuration / environment / queries.

Comment: We're currently using a RF of 2, so the data is on at least 2 nodes.
I decreased the timeout since I don't believe the queries that are failing would ever succeed. This way we can fail sooner. It looks like range queries timeout in 10 seconds by default.

I understand we should be able to handle failures, and we are catching the errors, but the delay in the request is the issue for us. I dont think a 3 node cluster should be experiencing timeouts with our load (small) This is my primary concern. I don't want more timeouts with more users, but this doesnt seem to be related to load.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of monitoring on the C* side to see if there could be any possible explanation with regards to delays?  I'd recommend taking a look at nodetool cfstats to see if that reveals anything, and monitoring any kind of os stats to see if that gives any insight.  Another thing that might be interesting to do is enabling query tracing which will help explain why queries could sometimes be taking a while.

Comment: We use new relic to monitor the server and the os stats, but nothing directly associated with cassandra, but all looks fine. I found the actual issue today, we are creating a long feed and a certain query using cassandra lucene plugin was taking a long time and we were firing off a lot of them at one time. This only happens every once in a while which is why it was hard to track down. I altered the query to not use the plugin and filter within our process instead and it works well now. Thanks!